# Docker expose a port of a container but restrict network access

Tags: docker, docker-networking

I have a server A, and it runs a container B (say an SSH server). I want to allow people doing some computation on B that does not access the network.

Using `docker run --publish=${MY_PORT}:22 ...`, I expose container B's port to allow people to connect into B. This way people can ssh into B using A's `${MY_PORT}` port. However, people can initiate TCP connections to other servers (e.g. `8.8.8.8`), so they can use server A a jump host to do bad things.

Is it possible to isolate container B's network? That is, only allow access to the published port, and deny all other network traffic. I am thinking of something similar to `--network=none --publish=${MY_PORT}:22`. Is it possible to achieve this without editing Docker's iptables?